# Projection of set of point on a line with chainage

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I am new to QGIS and in fact new to GIS mapping as whole.

I have a line in shp format (which does not have chainage & I want to add chainage added to it).

Chainage is the distance from the starting point of a line. I have tried using Qchainage Plugin to extract the distance (chainage) from one of the starting point. After that I used NNJoin Plugin to join two layer. Problem is, Qchainage doesn't add the attribute to the same layer of line which could be related to distance (chainage) & then related to multipoints.

Then I have several datapoints in the vicinity of the line. Attribute tables have been provided to all datapoints except the chainage along the line.

It would be helpful to first add chainage to the line & then project these points on the line with an added attribute termed as chainage.

Comment: And what is "chainage" supposed to be?

Comment: Chainage is the distance from the starting point of a line. The term is quite common to ones who are managing linear assests such as pipelines. I have tried using Qchainage tool (Plugin) to extract the distance (chainage) from one of the starting point. After that I have used nnjoin (Plugin) to join two layer. Problem is, Qchainage doesn't add the attribute to the same layer of line which could be related to distance (chainage) & then related to multipoints. Hope, you understand my problem and sorry for the english.

Comment: It's not possible to store chainage as attributes in a line layer, because each line is a single feature. The closest you can get is storing it in a separate point layer.